# Use of this keyword as an argument to the class constructor in Jenkins file

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I recently came across the following lines in Jenkinsfile

```
def obj = new Foo(this, params)
obj.someMethod()
```

what is the use of this keyword as an argument to the class constructor?

Comment: I have found this [link](https://rogerwelin.github.io/jenkins/continuous-delivery/2016/10/18/jenkins2.0-next-generation-of-pipeline-as-code.html) but I did not understand it completely what the author was trying to say about this keyword,

Comment: What type is `Git` in this example (built-in, a Jenkins plugin, or a custom type you have)? What are you trying to determine? Passing in `this` just means that the `Git` constructor takes in the `CpsScript` type in its constructor, but I don't know what you are looking for after that.

Comment: updated the question to avoid confusion? Anyways I came to know the use of it. Thanks!

Comment: @mkobit could you please highlight on the CpsScript part. what it means and what it does?

Comment: The short explanation is [`CpsScript`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsScript.java) is the base script class that every `Jenkinsfile` is compiled into. It is what `this` is inside of a `Jenkinsfile`

Answer (score 1):

**this** keyword is used to pass pipeline steps to a library class, in a constructor, or just one method

Suppose I have the following pipeline

```
pipeline{
  agent any
  stages {
    stage {
      steps {
        echo "Inside Steps block"
        script {
           echo "Hello World"
           sh 'date'
           def obj = new Bar(this)
           obj.test()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how the class file looks

```
class Bar implements Serializable {
  def steps
  Bar(steps) {
    this.steps = steps
  }

  void test() {
    this.steps.echo 'Hello World inside class Method'
    this.steps.sh 'date'
  }
}
```

So basically whatever steps you can execute inside pipeline can be used inside the groovy class by passing **this** keyword to the class constructor

More info can be found from the [official doc](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)